# How cast Enum to String in Stream API?

Tags: java, string, enums, stream

```
public class User {
    private String name;
    private Role role;
 }

enum Role {
    ADMIN, MODERATOR, USER
}

List<User> users = Arrays.asList(
                new User("Alex", Role.USER),
                new User("Tom", Role.ADMIN),
                new User("Bob", Role.MODERATOR),
                new User("Mila", Role.USER),
                new User("Kate", Role.MODERATOR)
        );

Map<Role, Long> count = users.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(User::getRole, Collectors.counting()));

Result : {ADMIN=1, USER=2, MODERATOR=2}
```

I want to group by role and calculate the number of users, using stream API.
When I used Map<**Role**, Long> all is ok.

But I need Map<**String**, Long> and have a compile error. I don't get how to cast Enum to String in this case?

Comment: `Collectors.groupingBy(user -> user.getRole().name(), ....)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `user.getRole().name()` instead of only `user.getRole()`.

`name()` method will return the name of your defined `Enum` (eg. ADMIN) in String format.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like below:

```
Map<String, Long> r = v.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(u -> u.getRole().toString(), Collectors.counting()));
```

**Test Code:**

```
List<User> v = Arrays.asList(new User("Alex", Role.USER), 
    new User("Tom", Role.ADMIN),
    new User("Bob", Role.MODERATOR), 
    new User("Mila", Role.USER), 
    new User("Kate", Role.MODERATOR));

Map<String, Long> r = v.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(u -> u.getRole().toString(), Collectors.counting()));

System.out.println(r);
```

**Output:**
{ADMIN=1, USER=2, MODERATOR=2}

**Role Enum:**

```
enum Role {
  USER, ADMIN, MODERATOR;
}
```

By Overriding `toString` in enum you can map to any key.

**User Class:**

```
class User {

  private Role role;

  private String name;

  public User(String name, Role role) {
    this.role = role;
    this.name = name;
  }

  /**
   * @return the domain
   */
  public Role getRole() {
    return role;
  }

  /**
   * @param role
   *          the role to set
   */
  public void setRole(Role role) {
    this.role = role;
  }

  /**
   * @return the name
   */
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  /**
   * @param name
   *          the name to set
   */
  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
```